# How do I enable the button, when editText.isNotBlank() and checkBox.isChecked?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have 2 editText fields, a checkbox and a button enabled to false. I need to enable the button when the edittext fields are not empty and the checkbox is checked.

```
buttonEnter.setOnClickListener {
            editTextLogin.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    editLogin = editTextLogin.text.toString()
                    buttonEnter.isEnabled = isButtonVisible(editLogin, editPassword, checkBoxAgreement)
                }
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
            })
            editTextPassword.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    editPassword = editTextPassword.text.toString()
                    buttonEnter.isEnabled = isButtonVisible(editLogin, editPassword, checkBoxAgreement)
                }
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
            })
            checkBoxAgreement.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
                buttonEnter.isEnabled = isButtonVisible(editLogin, editPassword, checkBoxAgreement)
            }
private fun isButtonVisible (a: String, b: String, c: CheckBox): Boolean {
        return a.isNotBlank() && b.isNotBlank() && c.isChecked
    }
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Make a function:

```
private fun updateButtonState() {
    buttonEnter.isEnabled = editLogin.isNotBlank() && editPassword.isNotBlank() && checkBoxAgreement.isChecked
}
```

Call it in the listeners of your text fields and check box:

```
        editTextLogin.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                editLogin = editTextLogin.text.toString()
                updateButtonState()
            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
        })
        editTextPassword.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                editPassword = editTextPassword.text.toString()
                updateButtonState()
            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
        })
        checkBoxAgreement.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            updateButtonState()
        }
```

Comment: Are you setting these listeners inside the button click listener like your code above looks like? I was assuming you snipped out some code in between because that wouldn’t make any sense. There is probably some bigger issue with your code but I can tell what it is without seeing more of your class.

Comment: I don't understand how can your answer be logically different from OP's attempt?

Comment: It’s not really. I just thought they were asking for a clean strategy for doing it. Copy-pasted code like that is error prone and harder to maintain.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yeah, yours is definitely cleaner. it's seems very odd to me that either of codes doesn't work though because logic seems to be OK.

Comment: thanks, yes, it didn't work because all this code was inside button click listener.